# Backend issue with uploader after SUPEE-8788 (CE 1.7.0.2)

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, supee-8788

I got an issue on backend, */catalog_product/edit after applying successfully the patch SUPEE-8788.

The error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined" is returned.

The uploader buttons are displayed but don't work (because of this JS error I guess).

Is someone got the same error?
If yes, how did you fixed it?

EDIT: This initial issue is now fixed.

---

No js merge is disabled (I'm working locally).

But I've found the problem.
The cause was: me ':)

I ran the PATCH on my distant server, then retrieve all the updated ressources locally.

I've just forgot to take the folder /js/mage/adminhtml/uploader

So now the uploader is opening the windows for file selecting.

BUT, when I click on "upload files", the uploader seems working fine, "complete" message is displayed.

BUT no image seems really uploaded (the file is not added  to the product images list).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error:

I got an issue on backend, */catalog_product/edit after applying successfully the patch SUPEE-8788.
The error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined" is returned.

I checked that the SWF files were there and the js files were there as listed in this post but was still getting the error.  These are the steps I took to mend it for my installations.

1. I checked that Merge JavaScript Files was off in system -> configuration -> developer
2. I went into General -> Design and made sure that themes -> default was set to "default" instead of the custom theme name.  I think this may have been the cause of the issue for me, perhaps it was looking for the files in the wrong place?
3. I emptied the cache in system -> cache managment -> select all -> refresh
4. I rebuilt the indexes (this wouldn't have made any difference but I did it)
5. I emptied the local browser cache.
6. I relogged in and it all worked.

YMMV but I hope that helps someone, I wasted a couple of hours on this.

Kind regards

Comment: check swf files are here: /skin/adminhtml/default/default/media

Comment: Merge js files was the fix for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The problem turned out to be that I had a customized version of `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml`. I merged the changes from the patch into my customized version and refreshed the Magento Caches. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Turned out an extension made IE run in IE-8 compatibility mode.

Look for some code like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=xxx" />` in your HTML (xxx is any IE version, in my case 8).

If you encounter this, you probably have the same issue. Try updating the module or fix the undelying problem.

Answer (score 1):

in my case

`js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js`
was missing.

I downloaded a fresh `magento 1.7.0.2` installation and upload to the mine.

Answer (score 0):

Is your merge JS enable in your site? So please disable it for admin and that will works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flush and Refresh Magento Cache.
2. Try re indexing.
3. check below swf files are exists in media folder, 
   -flex.swf
   -uploaderSingle.swf
   -uploader.swf

**Path to check :**`skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/`

4. lastly clear browser cache and check again.

Comment: Why my suggestion edit is rejected?

Comment: Step 3, should swf the files exist or not exist? What should one do if they are found/not found?

Comment: All those 4 steps are done. No joy, still having the same issue ?? anyone fixed this issue. please help me. i am ran in 1.9.1.0